# what is wrong with this code.. regarding strncat

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

sorry i modified the code now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>        

void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char** f=NULL;
    char* ff=NULL;

    ff="abcd";

    f=( char**)malloc ((i + 1) * sizeof (char *)+5);
    f[0]=ff;
 // strcpy(f[0],ff); (this again giving same error)
    strncat(f[0],"efg",3);
    printf("f : %s",f[0]);
}
```

I am getting some unhandled exception, Access violation writing error. Can anyone explain me the error I did here.
NOTE : sorry i modified the code now:

Thanks for the answers

Comment: `void main` **RAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHH**

Comment: they say, "a little knowledge is a dangerous thing"... so true.. so true..

Comment: If you're working in C, then please don't cast the return value from `malloc`. If you're working in C++, then please use `new` instead of `malloc`. Also, what is `(i+1) * sizeof(char*) + 5` supposed to mean?

Comment: According to the Standard, there are only 2 permissible signatures for `main`:  `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: @John: The standard also allows others, but since this is tagged `[visual-c++]`, I'll let you off the hook. ;)

Comment: @Xeo:  Whether other parameters are acceptable is ambigious at best, but one thing is clear:  `main` must return an `int`.

Comment: @John: I was quite sure the standard allows freestanding (embedded) system to have a different return, but rereading in the C++03 standard doesn't deliver. :/

Comment: @Anil Kumar, still not going to work... You need to read your book, and if you have book, and you've learnt this, throw it away and get a different book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are setting f<-ff

ff points to the start of a constant char[] ("abcd")
and then you change the value of *f (which is exactly *ff) thus - access violation.

Comment: The error is more serious, because he is assigning a new value to the initialized pointer (leaking memory).

Comment: @Diego: yes, but is was not the question.

Comment: It IS the question, because he doesn't understand the basic memory management for strings in C.

Comment: I getting the points u have mentioned, can u check now, i have modified the code.. plz tell me how i am wrong here

Comment: @Anil Kumar: it is the same mistake, you are now setting ff<-"abcd" and then f[0]<-ff this will result in ff=="abcd" (the exact string in the exact address), and when you are trying to strncat() on f[0], you are actually doing it on the same "abcd", which result in trying to modify non-writeable memory.

Answer (score 5):

The second assign to `f` actually removes the first assign. To copy the original string you have to use strcpy. Also, note to reserve enough space in the malloc. It have to be the initial four characters of `"abcd"` plus the three more added `"efg"` plus one (the ending `\0`):

```
f = (char*)malloc(9); // 5+3+1
strcpy(f, ff);
strncat(f, "efg", 3);
```

Comment: Thanks Alot, can u check now, i have modified the code.. plz tell me how i am wrong here

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning f to ff.
So you are trying to concatenate a const string.
In short when you think doing a concatenation in the malloced area.

```
strncat(f,"efg",3);
```

Your are in fact doing this.

```
strncat(ff,"efg",3);



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *concat(const char *a, const char *b) {
   size_t la = strlen(a);
   size_t lb = strlen(b);
   char *ret= (char*) malloc( la + lb + 1 /* for \0 */);
   memcpy(ret,a,la);
   memcpy(ret+la,b,lb);
   ret[la+lb] = '\0';
   return ret;
}

void main()
{
    char* f=NULL;

    char *f =concat("abcd","efg");

    printf("f : %s",f[0]);
    free(f);
}
```

Comment: u got correct, actually i have changed the code, can u check now, plz tell me how i am wrong here

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate to ff which is not writable. That's why you are getting Access Violation.

You are setting `f = ff` which points the f pointer to ff. This leaks memory as well BTW.

`ff` is declared in code segment which is not writable and writing on it causes undefined behavior. That undefined behavior in your case is an Access Violation error.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo many things:

Firstly, this is a string literal, should be `const`

```
char* ff="abcd"; // should not do this

const char* ff = "abcd"; // instead
```

next is your `malloc` - argh

```
f=( char*)malloc ((i + 1) * sizeof (char *)+5);
```

What you want to do is to allocate 5 characters `(i + 1 == 1)`, you were also getting the `sizeof` a pointer (`char*`) rather than `char`

```
f=( char*)malloc (5 * sizeof (char));
```

next is this:

```
f=ff;
```

effectively you've overwritten the previous allocation and now `f` points to `ff`, which is why `strncat` fails! However even if you did not do that, `strncat` fails because `f` which you `malloc`d will not contain a NUL terminated string, and you'll have nasal daemons everywhere.

So, remove the above assignment, and `memset` the newly allocated block to `0`, and your code might just work. If you are using C++, then what you are doing is equivalent to

```
std::string f("abcd");
f.append("efg");
```

EDIT: I've undeleted this to point out the errors on your code rather than just why it is failing...

Comment: He needs to allocate space for 8 chars (4 + 3 + null termination). Using sizeof(char) is superfluous since sizeof(char) == 1 by definition. So malloc(8), or even better, calloc(1, 8). Also, you've missed the faulty declaration of main. Should be int main(int argc, char **argv). And then there is the faulty use of strncat which doesn't copy the string termination. I'm impressed/awed/<random superlative> with the number of errors in such a short program.

Comment: Thnks alot for your explanation, can u check now, i have modified the code.. plz tell me how i am wrong here

Comment: @Klas Lindback, yes, too many, I only listed the real obvious stuff... :) With regards to `sizeof`, I think it's good habit to get into from the start - it may be superflous, but it's a thing for the compiler to worry about...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char* ff="abcd";
> ```

- `"abcd"` is `const char*`, not `char*`

> ```
> f=( char*)malloc ((i + 1) * sizeof (char *)+5);
> ```

- `i` is 0, you mean `strlen(ff)+1`
- `char *` instead of `char`
- `5` is just confused?

> ```
> f=ff;
> ```

- `f` is set to the same *pointer value* as `ff`, ie make `f` point to the same const string `"abcd"`
- memory leak, since you didn't free `f=malloc` first

> ```
> strncat(f,"efg",3);
> ```

- `3` is too little, it should include the trailing `\0` - use at least 4 to copy the entire `"efg"`
- it should actually be the size of the destination - the size you used in `malloc` above
  (or more precise the minimum of source and destination size.)

> ```
> printf("f : %s",f);
> ```

- missing trailing `\n` (newline)

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ff;
ff = "whatever";
```

`ff` is assigned a string literal, which cannot be changed. This piece of string is stored in the `.rodata` area of the executable in linux, and a similar readonly area in other types of executables. So after the assignment of the string literal `ff = "whatever"`  `ff` contains an address in memory which is *read-only*. By doing: `char f[0] = ff` and then trying to modify the string `f[0]` which actually points to `ff` which again points to the base address of the string `whatever\0` stored in the memory which is read only, which you try to modify, which the OS stops you from doing.

Either You do :

```
  char *ff;
  ff = malloc (sizeof (char) * SIZE_OF_YOUR_CHOICE);
  strcpy (ff, "whatever");
  /* now do what ever modification (within the size limits) */
  free (ff);
```

Or you do :

```
char ff[SIZE_OF_YOUR_CHOICE] = "whatever";
/* not do whatever modification (within the size limits) */
```